# How to get date from a video via Youtube Python data API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get the date of the video published with Youtube video id using Youtube Python data API. Is this possible?

I tried using all `part` parameters that are possible, but no parameter is linked to Youtube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you missed [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint with [`part=snippet`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) which returns [`publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.publishedAt).